How do I simulate collisions between spheres in a compute shader? (GLSL)
I have a system of 1000 particles that go through a sort of n-body simulation on the GPU, where each particle can interact with each other particle. I would like to achieve something that looks like soap bubbles or cell division, where the collision does not have to be rigid but each sphere pushes against its neighbors, making the overall structure expand no more than necessary.
Workgroup size is 10x10x10.
Here is my shader:
#[compute]
#version 450

layout(local_size_x = 10, local_size_y = 10, local_size_z = 10) in;

layout(set = 0, binding = 0, std430) restrict buffer MyPositionXBuffer {
    float data[];
}
my_position_x_buffer;
layout(set = 0, binding = 1, std430) restrict buffer MyPositionYBuffer {
    float data[];
}
my_position_y_buffer;
layout(set = 0, binding = 2, std430) restrict buffer MyPositionZBuffer {
    float data[];
}
my_position_z_buffer;

layout(set = 0, binding = 3, std430) restrict buffer MyVelocityXBuffer {
    float data[];
}
my_velocity_x_buffer;
layout(set = 0, binding = 4, std430) restrict buffer MyVelocityYBuffer {
    float data[];
}
my_velocity_y_buffer;
layout(set = 0, binding = 5, std430) restrict buffer MyVelocityZBuffer {
    float data[];
}
my_velocity_z_buffer;


float webby_force(float dist) {
    //return clamp(pow(dist, 16.0), 0.0, 10.0);
    float force_reversal_dist = 0.5;
    return -clamp(pow((dist - force_reversal_dist) * 100.0, 3.0), -100.0, 100.0);
}


float attraction(float dist) {
    //return pow(dist - 0.9, 3.0);
    
    dist = clamp(dist, 0.0, 1.0);
    float value = pow(asin(dist - 0.1), 5.0);
    value = clamp(value, -1.0, 1.0);
    return value;
}


float simple_force(float dist) {
    float diff = dist - 0.1;
    float mult = 50.0;
    float value = pow(diff * mult, 5.0) * max((-abs(diff) * 2.0) + 0.05, 0.0);
    value = clamp(value, -1.0, 1.0);
    return -value;
}


float repulsion(float dist) {
    float diff = dist - 0.1;
    return clamp(pow(diff * 100.0, 2.0), -5.0, 5.0);
}


float is_colliding(float dist) {
    return max(-sign(dist - 0.1), 0.0);
}


float neighbor_is_not_self(uint loc, uint loc_neighbor) {
    return abs(sign(loc - loc_neighbor));
}


void main() {
    uint location = ((gl_WorkGroupID.x * gl_NumWorkGroups.x * gl_NumWorkGroups.x) + (gl_WorkGroupID.y * gl_NumWorkGroups.x) + (gl_WorkGroupID.z));
    vec3 position = vec3(my_position_x_buffer.data[location], my_position_y_buffer.data[location], my_position_z_buffer.data[location]);
    vec3 velocity = vec3(my_velocity_x_buffer.data[location], my_velocity_y_buffer.data[location], my_velocity_z_buffer.data[location]);
    
    vec3 neighbor_pos = vec3(my_position_x_buffer.data[gl_LocalInvocationIndex], my_position_y_buffer.data[gl_LocalInvocationIndex], my_position_z_buffer.data[gl_LocalInvocationIndex]);
    uint i = 1000;
    vec3 tinyvec = vec3(my_position_x_buffer.data[i], my_position_y_buffer.data[i], my_position_z_buffer.data[i]);
    vec3 neighbor_vec = normalize(neighbor_pos - position + tinyvec);
    vec3 neighbor_vec_unnorm = neighbor_pos - position + tinyvec;
    
    memoryBarrierShared();
    
    float distance_multiplier = 1.0;
    
    // collision detection
    float neighbor_not_self_flag = float(neighbor_is_not_self(location, gl_LocalInvocationIndex));
    float neighbor_dist = distance(position, neighbor_pos);
    float collision_flag = is_colliding(neighbor_dist * distance_multiplier) * neighbor_not_self_flag;
    float no_collision_flag = 1.0 - collision_flag;
    
    // calculated forces
    float repulsive_factor = repulsion(neighbor_dist * distance_multiplier);
    float webby_factor = webby_force(neighbor_dist * distance_multiplier);
    float simple_force_factor = simple_force(neighbor_dist * distance_multiplier);
    
    memoryBarrierShared();
    
    float force_multiplier = 1.0;
    
    // force integration
    vec3 neighbor_force = neighbor_vec_unnorm * force_multiplier * simple_force_factor * webby_factor;
    vec3 center_force = normalize(position + tinyvec) * length(position) * 0.00001;
    
    memoryBarrierShared();
    
    float damping = 0.9;
    
    velocity += neighbor_force + center_force;
    velocity *= damping;
    
    memoryBarrierShared();
    
    vec3 newposition = position - velocity;
    
    memoryBarrierShared();

    my_position_x_buffer.data[location] = newposition.x;
    my_position_y_buffer.data[location] = newposition.y;
    my_position_z_buffer.data[location] = newposition.z;
    my_velocity_x_buffer.data[location] = velocity.x;
    my_velocity_y_buffer.data[location] = velocity.y;
    my_velocity_z_buffer.data[location] = velocity.z;
}


Combining simple_force_factor with webby_factor was desperation, normally I would use just one of the functions at a time.
I know it's a mess, but I have tried many ways to calculate the force between spheres and have had little success. Here are some results that were interesting but not desired:
gif 1
gif 2
gif 3
What am I doing wrong? How far off am I? How many of those memoryBarriers are actually necessary? Any help is appreciated, thanks.

is there a way you can step through the shader and inspect the variables to make sure they're what you're expecting?
